# Retrieving both mobile numbers (sim - 1 & sim - 2) in android dual sim programatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am working for an android application that needs to retrieve/fetch both sim numbers from dual sim mobile and should display to the user, Based on selecting particular sim number by the user - need to register and send OTP to the selected sim number.

I am getting default sim number (**sim-1 or sim-2**) but, I am not getting both sim numbers from dual sim mobile.

For this I have googled many sites and links. But, I haven't got any answer relevant to my requirement.

> - I have used **`TelephonyManager`** class but it returns only Line1 number.

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
    telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

> - I have also tried **`SubscriptionManager`** class - From this class I am gettig both numbers but, that numbers should be present in
>     Settings-->Sim Management. for some devices by default numbers are
>     unknown and that tooo not editable. In this case I am not able to
>     fetch both sim numbers.

```
 try {
        String simTwoNumber, simOneNumber;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            SubscriptionManager subManager = (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
            List<SubscriptionInfo> subInfoList = null;
            subInfoList = subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            if (subInfoList != null && subInfoList.size() > 0) {
                switch (subInfoList.size()) {
                    case 2:
                        simTwoNumber = subInfoList.get(1).getNumber();
                    case 1:
                        simOneNumber = subInfoList.get(0).getNumber();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

added below permission in `Manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**Can anyone pls help me out on this.** or **pls give any suggestion to retrieve both sim numbers in android programatically.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that you can't trust in the phonennumber from the sim? It is mandatory and can differ from the real used number.